# Firebase query dont display any data if data dont exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Firebase query don't display any data if data don't exist no null no undefined , nothing no message at all , it only shows if it find something in the database.

```
  const ref =  this.fb.database().ref("Users");
     var self = this;

      ref.orderByChild('cellphone').equalTo('+351' + this.phoneNumber.toString()).on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val().cellphone);

        if (snapshot.exists()){
          let toast = self.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'Cellphone already exist',
            duration: 2000,
            position: 'bottom'
          });

          toast.present();
        }

        if(!snapshot.exists()){ // it dont even get here 
          console.log('can register');
        }

    });
```

My db structure, so if it does not find my cellphone does not shot nothing at all

[image: my db]

Comment: Have you tried using "value" instead of "child_added" event? That is likely the issue here.

Comment: @BurhanB yep was the problem thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was `using "value" instead of "child_added"`

The `child_added` event fires for each matching child under the node that you query. If there are no matching children, it will not fire.

This means that to test whether a node exists, you must use a `value` handler. And since a query can have multiple results, you will need to loop over the children.